# does ansi c allows serial communication on rs232 null modem?

Tags: c, serial-port

does ansi c allows serial communication on rs232 null modem?

if yes then any one give me example?

thanx in advance

Comment: Are you talking about writing a driver for a physical UART device, or an application that transfers data over a serial link?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ansi C has nothing to do with serial communications. ANSI C is a formal description of the C language, it doesn't define libraries. Communicating with an RS-232 modem is possible with C language, but it will be completely different in different platforms (Windows, Linux, embedded processors).

Answer (score 2):

It does, in as much as there's nothing in the language which prevents it, but it depends on your OS/platform to provide access to an appropriate device driver (or an abstraction of one).

For an (elaborate) example, refer to the source to the [minicom package](http://alioth.debian.org/projects/minicom/) (GPL). Something simpler (on a POSIX-like platform) might involve `open`ing a device node, using `ioctl` to configure it (baud rate etc), then you can simply `read` and `write` on the open file descriptor.